# Как записать массив в одну ячейку бд

Tags: php, mysql

Всем првиет!

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос. Но у меня возникли трудности с php , что я хочу записать массив который получаю из формы с одинаковыми `name` в одну ячеку с разделителем.

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" onlyread>
<input type="text" name="title[]" onlyread>
```

Я думал что можно через цикл, но не вышло.

Подскажите пожалуйста какими средства запроса sql можно это сделать?

Comment: не надо ничего записывать в одну ячейку с разделителем. Потом будет очень больно. Записывать надо в разные ячейки отдельной таблицы

Comment: @Ипатьев  даже если я потом просто хочу выводить как текст?

Comment: В особенности если потом выводить как текст

Comment: Вы в любой момент сможете соединить значения колонки в sql запросе http://old.code.mu/sql/group_concat.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно преобразовать массив в строку перед записью в базу [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

```php
        $array = ['title1', 'title2', 'tittle3'];
        $string = implode('----', $array);
```

Можно перед записью в БД преобразовать массив в Json [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode) и записать строкой в ячейку если важно сохранить сам массив. Потом при получении из БД [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) и будет снова массив.

Comment: Сериализируем всю БД, сжимаем gzip'ом и записываем в одну ячейку другой БД.